# How to slide an ImageView from left to right smoothly in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I need to make an `ImageView` slide from left to right of the screen with a smooth animation (I want the `ImageView` to be visible during the transition) I tried with the following code:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;

camion.animate()
    .translationX(width)
    .setDuration(2000)
    .setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator())
    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            //camion.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```

The `ImageView` moves but the animation is laggy and not smooth like I want to.
What am I doing wrong on the code?

Comment: see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12999391/2337837

Comment: @ZiedRebhi I tried the example but the animation is still laggy

Comment: Just curious, what device are you testing this on? Or are you testing on an emulator?

Comment: @Dom i'm testing it on a Moto G 2014 with android L

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Creating this kind of tween animation is simple. Just follow the steps,

**Step 1**

Create a directory `anim` inside the `res` directory and put this as `slide.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

   <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="75%p"
        android:duration="800" />
</set>
```

You can obviously customize the animation by changing the two attributes `fromXDelta` and `toXDelta`. The **%p** refers to with **respect to the parent** which simply means that it will move the image 75% with respect to the parent.

**Step 2**

```
// Refer the ImageView like this
imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);

// Load the animation like this
animSlide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                    R.anim.slide);

// Start the animation like this
imageView.startAnimation(animSlide);
```

You can also `setInterpolator()` and `setListeners()` if you want to. I haven't shown them here to keep it simple. If you need, just let me know.

**NOTE**

As you have mentioned repeatedly, that you are experiencing a **laggy animation**. I have tested this animation on **3 real devices and 2 emulators and the animation was buttery smooth** on all of them. Tested on low end devices like Moto E to high end devices like Nexus 5 and Galaxy S6.

If you still have a lag running this code, then the test device must be the reason. The code is perfect.

**UPDATE**

I just checked on my Moto G running on Lollipop too, the animation is running smoothly. This is a very small and light-weight animation, and should never be laggy. If you are still getting a lag, then **it must be the device you are testing, or some other piece of code on that Activity making the UI slow or unresponsive**.

Try to check which one is applicable to you,

- I have tested on a total of 6 devices now with no lag at all. So, you can be rest assured that your production app will not have any lag, it can be your device which is slow
- If you are doing some heavy operations like **accessing the file system, database, or any other heavy operation, it must be slowing down the UI thread and you are loosing frames.** Try to use `AsyncTask` for these heavy operations

Comment: ok I've tried it but on my Moto G it's still laggy. I'm going to test it on other 2 devices soon, i'll let you know!

Comment: The problem was the background image that was way too big and required lot of cpu to render, I've reduced its size and now it's working fine, ty a lot for your answer! I'll give you the bounty as soon as I can

Comment: Glad to know that it is working fine now. I have also spent a lot of time testing it on so many devices just for you. Hope you will accept the answer and reward the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: @Signo Will it be possible to accept the answer and reward the bounty? I have just upvoted your question too.

Comment: I needed to wait 22 hours to accept the answer, one more hour and i'll be able to accept!

Comment: @Signo I can understand. Not a problem at all. It would be great if you can assign the bounty. Thanks.

Comment: buttery smooth indeed +1

Comment: @ Aritra Roy  :Your answer is perfect..Thank you.And any other way to repeat this animation in a loop ??

Answer (score 6):

Try this. It will animate the imageview.

```
        ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        float width = display.getWidth();
        TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, width - 50, 0, 0); // new TranslateAnimation(xFrom,xTo, yFrom,yTo)
        animation.setDuration(1000); // animation duration
        animation.setRepeatCount(5); // animation repeat count
        animation.setRepeatMode(2); // repeat animation (left to right, right to
                                    // left )
        // animation.setFillAfter(true);

        img_animation.startAnimation(animation); // start animation
```

Comment: I already tried this solution (I've found it on an old SO question) but the animation is laggy even with this method

Comment: ok i am trying to do this for you. until wait for some more answers

Comment: once look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860780/animate-imageview-width-without-scaling

Comment: mm I don't think that's they want to achieve watching the fiddle, I tried the method but it scales the image

Answer (score 6):

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0, -view.getWidth(), 0, 0);
animate.setDuration(500);
animate.setFillAfter(true);
view.startAnimation(animate);
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this works for u

**animation.xml**

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Animation" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_animation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
        android:src="@drawable/emo_im_laughing" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Animation.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Animation extends Activity {

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.);

  ImageView img_animation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_animation);

  TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 400.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f);
  animation.setDuration(5000);
  animation.setRepeatCount(5);
  animation.setRepeatMode(2);
  animation.setFillAfter(true);
  img_animation.startAnimation(animation);

 }
}
```

Comment: How to get current position of view after end of translate animation ??

Answer (score 3):

try the code below

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1500.0f); // new TranslateAnimation (float fromXDelta,float toXDelta, float fromYDelta, float toYDelta)
animation.setDuration(2000); // animation duration
animation.setRepeatCount(1); // animation repeat count if u repeat only once set to 1 if u don't repeat set to 0
animation.setFillAfter(false);
your_view .startAnimation(animation);//your_view for mine is imageView
```

Comment: How to get current position of view after end of translate animation ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       int windowwidth;
       int windowheight;

       private LayoutParams layoutParams;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
              setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

              windowwidth = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
              windowheight = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();
              final ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

              img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                     @Override
                     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                           LayoutParams layoutParams = (LayoutParams) img
                                         .getLayoutParams();
                           switch (event.getAction()) {
                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                  break;
                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                  int x_cord = (int) event.getRawX();
                                  int y_cord = (int) event.getRawY();

                                  if (x_cord > windowwidth) {
                                         x_cord = windowwidth;
                                  }
                                  if (y_cord > windowheight) {
                                         y_cord = windowheight;
                                  }

                                  layoutParams.leftMargin = x_cord - 25;
                                  layoutParams.topMargin = y_cord - 75;

                                  img.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                                  break;
                           default:
                                  break;
                           }
                           return true;
                     }
              });
       }
}
```

Comment: There are already several answer to this question including one that has been accepted. You might want to edit your answer to explain how it is different from the others and what its advantages are.

Answer (score 0):

To Move `imageview`

from **Right to Left** Using @Aritra Roy Answer.

Use this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="75%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="100000" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now we have MotionLayout try to use that for very clean and smooth sliding animation.